# Using scanner to read input statement

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i'm writing code to read simple statement of words like "one two three", and put each word into an array String [] token, i wanted to input the statement using Scanner but it only read the first word. 
when i use the main method to input the statement it works well. 
can i know what is my mistake?

here are the 2 Codes:

//Using main method:

```
public class MyLangyage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String statement = "one two three";
        screen(statement);
    }
    public static void screen(String statement) {
        String token[]= statement.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(token[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

the result at the console will be:

*one
two
three*

//Using The Scanner:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyLangyage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String statement = scanner.next();
        screen(statement);
    }
    public static void screen(String statement) {
        String token[]= statement.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(token[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

if i write at console:

*one two three*

then press enter the result will be:

*one*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `scanner.next()` which gets the next word it reads. If you want to read the whole line and then split use [`scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Either split a whole input line, or use the Scanner to get one token at a time.  Don't do both.

If you want to pull in multiple words from a `Scanner`, then you'll have to use `scanner.next()` more than once -- indeed, once per word.